# JMagick - How to convert a picture from CMYK to RGB?

Tags: java, imagemagick, rgb, cmyk, jmagick

I know there exists another post dealing with that problem [How to convert colorspace using JMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492766/how-to-convert-colorspace-using-jmagick.com) but but there is something I do not understand:

```
    String baseName = "Pictures/";
    String fileName = "dragon.gif";
     MagickImage imageCMYK;
     try {
     ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo( baseName + fileName);
     info.setColorspace(ColorspaceType.CMYKColorspace);

     System.out.println("ColorSpace BEFORE => " + info.getColorspace());

     imageCMYK = new MagickImage( info );


     System.out.println("ColorSpace AFTER => " +
             imageCMYK.getColorspace());
```

When I create the new MagickImage, the CMYKColorSpace is not kept as I obtain :

ColorSpace BEFORE => 12 (CMYK)

How to correctly convert a picture from CMYK to RGB ?

Thanks.

ColorSpace AFTER => 1 (RGB)

Comment: Whichever way you end up doing this, be very mindful of the effect and need for colour profiles in this process.

Comment: When you write the image, why is the set ColorSpace lost ?

imageCMYK.writeImage(info);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** You are using `GIF` images. They don't support "CMYK" so the transform won't work for you (see [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=6162) forum post at imagemagick's web site)!

---

Use [`MagicImage.rgbTransformImage(ColorspaceType.CMYKColorspace)`](http://downloads.jmagick.org/jmagick-doc/magick/MagickImage.html#rgbTransformImage%28int%29). From the API:

> public boolean **rgbTransformImage**(int colorspace) throws MagickException
>
> Converts the reference image from RGB to an alternate colorspace. The transformation matrices are not the standard ones: the weights are rescaled to normalized the range of the transformed values to be [0..MaxRGB].

---

Example:

```
try {
    MagickImage image = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo(baseName + fileName));

    if (!image.rgbTransformImage(ColorspaceType.CMYKColorspace))
         throw new Exception("Couldn't convert image color space");

    ...
} catch (MagickException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
But there is still a problem because once you have written your image :

                 
imageCMYK.writeImage(info);
   
   
System.out.println("ColorSpace AFTER => " +
     imageCMYK.getColorspace());

RGBColorSpace comes back....

WHY ?

Comment: Oh, I see your your working with `".gif"` files. I don't think they support CMYK. Updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

This still won't work for other image formats such as PNG.